# Updating react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have this piece of code:

```
let columnChooser = [productName]

      function replacer (key: any) {

        if (key == 1) {
            message.info(`Click on item ${key}`);
            columnChooser.push(productPrice)
        }
      }
```

what I want basically is to add `productPrice` into the existing array. With this method in my react return Ido not get a new column `productPrice`, I constantly have only `productName`. the function is from the drop-down menu and it grabs key values so an appropriate column can be added to the array.

Can anyone provide me with some insight into why this is not working

after function is run via button press I expected that new value be added into array and shown in front end

Comment: Why not to use `===` instead of `==`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you need to use useState. Then your code would look like this:

```
// let columnChooser = [productName]
   const [columnChooser, setColumnChooser] = useState ([productName]);

      function replacer (key: any) {

        if (key == 1) {
            message.info(`Click on item ${key}`);
            setColumnChooser(prevState => [...prevState, productPrice]);
           // columnChooser.push(productPrice)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite understand your end goal, but from what I understand you want to update the value in a component. For that you can use the useState of React Hooks and the click event of the button.
example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6vryxv96pz

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState(["a", "b", "c"]);

  const onChangeValue = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const onAddItem = () => {
    setList((prevState) => {
      const list = [...prevState, value];
      return list;
    });
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <div>{item}</div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChangeValue} />
      <button type="button" onClick={onAddItem} disabled={!value}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and apologize for not being clear. Here is the whole code for the page:

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-breeze-p23p26?file=/list.tsx
basically, I want to have the option to add and remove columns in the list in this app. I am using refine framework and antdesign. Once the function is running I get the message but the column is not added in front.